# Is there another way to fetch the Circle object present in a JSON from Fabric JS?

Tags: json, fabricjs

I'm trying to fetch the JSON from a canvas using FabricJS, It is fetching image type, rect type correctly, the issue seems to be happening only with circle.

The circle seems to break, as in the controls show, but the stroke is not visible.

I am posting my JSON below

`{
  "version": "3.4.0",
  "objects": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "version": "3.4.0",
      "originX": "left",
      "originY": "top",
      "left": 0,
      "top": 40,
      "width": 1200,
      "height": 800,
      "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
      "stroke": null,
      "strokeWidth": 0,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeDashOffset": 0,
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit": 4,
      "scaleX": 1,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": null,
      "visible": true,
      "clipTo": null,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "paintFirst": "fill",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "transformMatrix": null,
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "id": 0,
      "selectable": false,
      "src": "http://126.0.0.122/airlift/upload/inspection/4/AP00004-0-Eksempelbilde%205%20Helikopter-1200x900.JPG",
      "filters": []
    },
    {
      "type": "circle",
      "version": "3.4.0",
      "originX": "left",
      "originY": "top",
      "left": 509,
      "top": 361,
      "width": 60,
      "height": 60,
      "fill": "",
      "stroke": "#fced7e",
      "strokeWidth": 1,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeDashOffset": 0,
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit": 4,
      "scaleX": 1,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": null,
      "visible": true,
      "clipTo": null,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "paintFirst": "fill",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "transformMatrix": null,
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "id": "1",
      "selectable": true
    }
  ]
}`

This issue happens when I use `loadFromJSON` Only rectangles and images seem to be retained.

I am attempting to add a number to the object, adding snippet below

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
  //console.log("Object: ", object[o]);
  if(object.id > 0){
    t = new fabric.Text(String(object.id), {
      left: parseInt(object.left) - 15,
      top: parseInt(object.top) - 15,
      fill: object.stroke,
      originX: object.originX,
      originY: object.originY,
      fontSize: 15
    });        
    canvas.add(t);
  }
});
```

`object.id` is a predefined id that holds the number to which I am adding text

Adding images for reference.

**BEFORE**

[image: This is the image before the issue occurs]

**AFTER**

[image: This is what happens when the issue occurs]

Comment: Which version of fabricjs you are using? In circle object, radius is missing, that's why it is not able to draw.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Durga let me just check on the radius. The FabricJS version is 3.4.0

Comment: @Durga After adding the radius it helped. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Are you adding it manually??

Comment: No I used the `toObject()` function and in any case I was adding it on button click. It was showing the only issue was saving to json and fetching it back, possible reason cos of the radius as you mentioned.

Comment: By default toObject() from circle object will return radius as well.

Comment: But it wasn't storing the radius for some reason, in spite of setting it in the circle declaration

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle/ snippet here?

Comment: Is [this your question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/fabricjs/okxybdz_nZ0/9Ec4OnPPAwAJ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the fabric `toObject()` method to include custom properties. Since the loaded json is missing the radius you can do:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
            return function () {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                    radius: this.radius || null
                });
            };
        })(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

You can also include semi major and minor radii for ellipses:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
            return function () {
                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                    radius: this.radius || null,
                    rx: this.rx || null,
                    ry: this.ry || null
                });
            };
        })(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

Set this up prior to your code.